# iOS layout why does center constraint not enough?

Tags: ios

I really don't understand the logic of this ... well ... strange iOS layout system.

I place a UILabel with the constraint Align center X to Superview.

Why does it complain to need a new constraint for X position ??

center is center no?

Comment: It also needs to know if the width is fixed, or if it should expand with the screen.

Comment: Also, have a look at [Ray Wenderlich's 2 part tutorial on autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell more about the horizontal positioning of the view. Centering the view does not say wether it has a fixed width or it should keep the leading / trailing space around view.

Here are two possible options (there is also a fixed height with a fixed aspect ratio, as @Moshe said in his answer):

1. Your view will always have a width of 61 (for example):

[image: Fixed width]

2. Your view will have a fixed leading and trailing space on the left/right side:

[image: Leading / trailing]

Comment: Ok, that solves my problem but according to the different sentences length based on different languages, is it possible to tell the label to use all horizontal space available in a container?

Comment: You can use the second option and set 0 for the leading and trailing space

Answer (score 4):

That warning is a misnomer. It doesn't mean there's no constraint. It should say that "there aren't enough constraints to calculate an X position."

You need to add a constraint for X the position, but you also need to give enough constraints to for auto layout to figure out the width of your view.

You can either provide a Leading Space and a Trailing Space, or you can provide a Width, or you can provide a Height and a Ratio. Autolayout just needs something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have added a center x constraint, that should be enough for auto layout to calculate the x position. But are you sure you didn’t set a center **y** constraint instead? The directions that you drag the lines in Interface Builder can be confusing, so you might have accidentally set a **y** constraint when you meant to set an **x** constraint. If you are trying to center x, you will still need a constraint for the y position, whether it’s vertical centering or space from top or bottom to the superview or some other view.